# How to update Ggplot with selectsize input in R shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want to update ggplot. Here i have used plot function but instead of that i want to use ggplot that update automatically. GGplot automatically update with selectsizeinput. How to do that ?? Thanks in advance.

```
ui.r
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Multivariable plot"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", label = h3("Select CSV File")),
      checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'col names', value = TRUE),
      radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Seperator', choices = c("comma"=',',"semi comma"=';'), selected = ','),

      #checkboxGroupInput("choices1", label = h3("Wybierz Kolumny"), choices = NULL),
      # there is combobox to pick column
      selectInput("combobox", label = h3("x var"),choices = NULL),
     #selectInput("combobox1", label = h3("y var"),choices = NULL)
     selectizeInput("combobox1", label = h3("y var"), choices = NULL ,multiple = TRUE )

    ),

    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tb")
    )
  )
))
server.r

function(input, output, session){

  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    dataSet <- read.csv(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header )

    #updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "choices1", choices = colnames(dataSet))
    # this line updates selection in combobox 
    updateSelectInput(session, "combobox", choices = colnames(dataSet))
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "combobox1", choices = colnames(dataSet), server = TRUE)
    dataSet
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    data()    
  })

  output$multivarplot <- reactivePlot(function(){ 
   x    <- data()[, input$combobox]
    ydat    <- data.frame(data()[, input$combobox1])

     xval<-data.frame(x,ydat)
  #  ggplot(xval, aes(x = reorder(x, -x), y = y))+geom_point(colour='red')
   #g= ggplot(xval, aes(x,ydat[,1]))+geom_point(colour='red')

     ny <- ncol(ydat)
         par(mfcol=c(12,12),mfrow=c(1,1))

         if(ny==1)
           plot.default(x,ydat[,1],xaxt="n",col="blue")
     axis(1, at=1:length(xval$x),labels = xval$x)
 if     (ny==2)
        { y1 <- ydat[,1]
         y2 <- ydat[,2]
     plot.default(x, y1, ylim = range(c(y1,y2)),col='red')
         points(x,y2)}

  })


  output$tb <- renderUI({
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table")),

                  tabPanel("Plot", 
                           plotOutput("multivarplot")))
  })
}
```

Comment: please make a minimal example reproducing the behavior you don't like and provide  detailed expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a `ggplot` that updates based on the `selectInput` and `SelectizeInput`. As far as I understand you would like to plot more than one variable on the y-axis, so I have used `data.table` to `melt` the data into a `data.table` with three columns (`x_var`, `variable`, `value`), i.e. to a long format. That transformation (and any other calculations) could/should be moved to the `data()` reactive function.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Multivariable plot"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", label = h3("Select CSV File")),
      checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'col names', value = TRUE),
      radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Seperator',
        choices = c("comma"=',',"semi comma"=';'), selected = ','),
      selectInput("combobox", label = h3("x var"), choices = NULL),
      selectizeInput("combobox1", label = h3("y var"), choices = NULL,
        multiple = TRUE )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table")),
                  tabPanel("Plot",  plotOutput("multivarplot")))
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session){

  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    dataSet <- read.csv(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep,
      header = input$header)
    updateSelectInput(session, "combobox", choices = colnames(dataSet))
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "combobox1", choices = colnames(dataSet),
      server = TRUE)
    dataSet
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    data()    
  })

  output$multivarplot <- renderPlot({ 
    dt <- data.table(data())
    x_var <- input$combobox
    y_var <- input$combobox1
    if (!is.null(x_var) & !is.null(y_var)) {
      dt_melt <- melt(dt, id.vars = x_var, measure.vars = y_var)
      ggplot(dt_melt, aes_string(x = x_var, y = "value", group = "variable",
                            colour = "variable")) + geom_point(size = 3)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```